# osg, COLOR_BUFFER1 how to use it?

Tags: opengl, buffer, openscenegraph

I am creating a program to better understand the rendering process and defered render. In it I need to pass from a fragment shader a normal texture of the screen and send it to another pipeline.

#### I tried to archive it using the following lines:

```cpp
/////////////////////

osg::ref_ptr<osg::Texture2D> normText = new osg::Texture2D();

normText->setDataVariance(osg::Object::DYNAMIC);

normText->setInternalFormat(GL_RGBA);

cam2->attach(osg::Camera::COLOR_BUFFER1, normText);

// And in the first fragment shader I'm trying to write in this COLOR_BUFFER1 like this:

gl_FragData[1]=vec4(myNormals,1);

/////////////////////
```

For some reason it does not work. With these I am passing as well a texture with colors and depth (they have their own buffer as far as I know...) and there is no problems with those two though.

Comment: What exactly does not work about this? Right now the only interesting bit of code I see is that you are using `GL_RGBA` for your normal G-Buffer and appear to be outputting the normal directly to it. `GL_RGBA` is *unsigned normalized*, that means any negative value in your normal will be clamped to **0.0**.

Comment: For some reason the program just ignores that i wrote COLOR_BUFFER1 and works as it was COLOR_BUFFER0
Sorry about the lack of information.

ps: myNormals are already normalized . But thank you, that's important indeed.

Comment: Well, a normalized vector can still have negative values. The only thing normalization does is make it so that the combined *length* of all components is **1.0**. So you have to do one extra step to move negative values into the range [**0.0**,**0.5**] and positive into (**0.5**, **1.0**] before you write to the texture. Likewise, after you read it you have to undo that. In any case, this sounds a lot like your draw buffers are only set to `COLOR_BUFFER0` - I am not familiar with OpenScenegraph, but in straight OpenGL in addition to attaching a buffer, you have to set up a draw buffer for it.

Comment: That would be something along the lines of `GLenum draw_buffers [] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 }; glDrawBuffers (2, draw_buffers);` I am sure OpenSceneGraph has something similar. When an FBO is initialized it defaults to only `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and that would explain your current behavior.

Comment: I understand. But i can't find how to do it at all... in the examples i didn't find any directions.In osg it has something to do with the cameras. looks like is something with cam->setDrawBuffer() but it just receives one parameter... I found something about "setImplicitBufferAttachmentMask()" too, but using it didn't change nothing at all...

Comment: Found out. Thank you =D Seens that if you use :
cam2->attach(osg::Camera::BufferComponent(osg::Camera::COLOR_BUFFER1), normText, 0, 1);
instead of 
cam2->attach(osg::Camera::COLOR_BUFFER1, normText);
It works, i don't know why though.